# Plot precipitation data onto a matplotlib basemap map

Tags: python, matplotlib-basemap, netcdf4

Inspired by the example *Plot precip with filled contours* from [this website](https://matplotlib.org/basemap/users/examples.html) I want to make a plot of yesterday's precipitation data, projected onto a map. The example from that website can, however, no longer be used as the data format of the precipitation data has changed.

My approach is as follows:

1. download the netCDF4-file from the National Weather Service website
2. open the netCDF4-file and extract the relevant information
3. create a map with `Basemap`
4. project the precipitation data onto the map

I guess my problem is that I do not understand the netCDF4-file format, and in particular the metadata, since the information about the grid origin of the precipitation data must be hidden somewhere in it.

My code looks as follows:

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
import netCDF4
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import os.path
import urllib
from mpl_toolkits.basemap import Basemap

# set date for precipitation (1 day ago)
precip_date  = datetime.utcnow() - timedelta(days=1)
precip_fname = 'nws_precip_1day_{0:%Y%m%d}_conus.nc'.format( precip_date )
precip_url   = 'http://water.weather.gov/precip/downloads/{0:%Y/%m/%d}/{1}'.format( precip_date, precip_fname )

# download netCDF4-file if it does not exist already
if not os.path.isfile( precip_fname ):
    urllib.urlretrieve( precip_url, precip_fname )

# read netCDF4 dataset and extract relevant data
precip_dSet = netCDF4.Dataset( precip_fname )
# spatial coordinates
precip_x    = precip_dSet['x'][:]
precip_y    = precip_dSet['y'][:]
# precipitation data (is masked array in netCDF4-dataset)
precip_data = np.ma.getdata( precip_dSet['observation'][:] )
# grid information 
precip_lat0  = precip_dSet[ precip_dSet['observation'].grid_mapping ].latitude_of_projection_origin
precip_lon0  = precip_dSet[ precip_dSet['observation'].grid_mapping ].straight_vertical_longitude_from_pole
precip_latts = precip_dSet[ precip_dSet['observation'].grid_mapping ].standard_parallel
# close netCDF4 dataset
precip_dSet.close()

fig1, ax1 = plt.subplots(1,1, figsize=(9,6) )

# create the map
my_map = Basemap( projection='stere', resolution='l', 
                  width=(precip_x.max()-precip_x.min()), 
                  height=(precip_y.max()-precip_y.min()),
                  lat_0=30,                         # what is the correct value here?
                  lon_0=precip_lon0,
                  lat_ts=precip_latts
                )
# white background
my_map.drawmapboundary( fill_color='white' )
# grey coastlines, country borders, state borders
my_map.drawcoastlines( color='0.1' )
my_map.drawcountries( color='0.5' )
my_map.drawstates( color='0.8' )

# contour plot of precipitation data
# create the grid for the precipitation data
precip_lons, precip_lats = my_map.makegrid( precip_x.shape[0], precip_y.shape[0] )
precip_xx, precip_yy     = my_map( precip_lons, precip_lats ) 
# make the contour plot
cont_precip = my_map.contourf( precip_xx, precip_yy, precip_data )

plt.show()
```

This is how the output looks like (yes, for the final plot the color-levels have to be adjusted):

[image]

I know that this is a very specific question, so any suggestions/hints are greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly you are able to make the plot but want hints on adding extras?

`xarray` is a fantastic toolbox for working with netCDF files. It works like `pandas` but for netCDF files and is a big improvement on 'netCDF4':

http://xarray.pydata.org/en/stable/

To specify specific contours you can input the levels:

```
 cont_precip = my_map.contourf( precip_xx, precip_yy, precip_data,levels=[10,20,30]) # Edit for exact contours needed
```

If you wanted you can add a colorbar:

```
fig1.colorbar(cont_precip,ax=ax1)
```